# ASP.NET linkbutton visible property issue

Tags: asp.net

I'm using a public variable called IsAdmin in the code behind of an aspx page.

```
 public partial class _news : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public bool IsAdmin = false;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if (User.Identity.Name.Contains("admin"))
    {
        IsAdmin = true;
    }
    else
    {
        IsAdmin = false;
    }
 }
```

And i use the property Visible='<%#IsAdmin%>' to assign to panels which i want to show if the user is an admin in the aspx design of the page. Strangely it works for the linkbuttons i've put on the repeater.

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible='<%#IsAdmin%>'>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# "news_edit.aspx?     Action=edit&id=" + Convert.ToString( Eval("news_id")) %>Edit</asp:LinkButton>

 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# "news.aspx?Action=delete&id=" + Convert.ToString( Eval("news_id")) %>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
        </asp:Panel>
```

and it works fine, however outside the repeater i've put another linkbutton without a panel

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/news_edit.aspx?action=new" Visible='<%#IsAdmin%>'>Add New Item</asp:LinkButton>
```

but the visible property doesn't work on it! I tried putting it inside a panel too and setting it's visible property but that too didn't work.

So i have following doubts

1)what is the issue?
2)what is the technical name when we use references like '<%#IsAdmin%>' in the design page
3)Does page load happen before page is rendered of after page is rendered?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%# %>` is the syntax used for accessing databound fields.  Since you are likely databinding the Repeater control at some point, these expressions will be evaluated.

Since you are likely *not* calling databind on the Panel and the Linkbuttons outside of the Repeater, these expressions will not be processed.  You can probably change them to something like

```
<%= IsAdmin.ToString() %>
```

and get the result you want.

Check this [great blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx) for more information on the differences.

Also, Page Load happens before the page is rendered.  Rendering the page is the last thing that happens in the ASP.Net page lifecycle.

Comment: hi upon using Visible="<%= IsAdmin.ToString() %>" i get the error
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= IsAdmin.ToString() %>' for the 'Visible' property.

What can be wrong now?

Comment: Try changing your double-quotes to single quotes: `Visible='<%= IsAdmin.ToString() %>'`.